# can I dispatch an action as an array instead of an object literal?

Tags: redux

I've tried it with a simple demonstration, and it seems to work. But just to make sure, is there anything in redux or redux middlewares that require an action to be an object with a 'type' property? I've read some tutorials that the 'type' property thing was emphasized to be a must-have.

Before:

```
dispatch({ type: 'DO_SOMETHING', info: 1 });
```

after:

```
dispatch(['DO_SOMETHING', 1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

@TomW is correct - you can't dispatch arrays with a standard Redux store.  It's possible to write middleware that look for arrays being dispatched and intercept them in some way.  However, anything that actually reaches the reducers *must* be a plain object with a `type` field.

You may want to read my blog post [Idiomatic Redux: The Tao of Redux, Part 1 - Implementation and Intent](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-1/), where I discuss the actual technical limitations that Redux requires and why those exist.  There's also a somewhat related discussion in [redux#1813](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/pull/1813), where someone submitted a pull request trying to add the ability to dispatch multiple actions at once without actually understanding how all the pieces fit together.

Answer (score 1):

The Redux documentation explicitly requires that you provide a type property:

http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html

> Actions are plain JavaScript objects. Actions must have a type property that indicates the type of action being performed. Types should typically be defined as string constants.

Furthermore, `Redux` appears to throw an exception in `dispatch` if you:

- Don't have a plain object: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/v3.7.0/src/createStore.js#L150
- With a type property: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/v3.7.0/src/createStore.js#L158

Do you have some middleware that is transforming the dispatched payload in some way?